# Getting KeyError: 2 when I run export_graphviz function

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, series

I want to build a Decision Tree model for my dataset and I use 'export graphviz' function then I got KeyError: 2

My code is

```
y_pred_gini = clf_gini.predict(X_test)

y_pred_train_gini = clf_gini.predict(X_train)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf_gini, out_file=None, 
                              feature_names=X_train.columns,  
                              class_names=y_train,
                              filled=True, rounded=True,  
                              special_characters=True)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
graph
```

My errors as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-55-7d8f7916ba06>", line 1, in <module>
    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf_gini, out_file=None,

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_export.py", line 788, in export_graphviz
    exporter.export(decision_tree)

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_export.py", line 424, in export
    self.recurse(decision_tree.tree_, 0,

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_export.py", line 484, in recurse
    '%d [label=%s' % (node_id, self.node_to_str(tree, node_id,

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_export.py", line 355, in node_to_str
    class_name = self.class_names[np.argmax(value)]

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)

  File "C:\Users\PPP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 2
```

Help me would be most appreciated

Comment: we don't have your data so we can't test it and we can't say what is wrong. Maybe first try `tree.export_graphviz(clf_gini)` and later try add arguments one by one to get which argument makes problem.

Comment: Thk u for your advice. After I tested, I found that my error is from 'class_names=y_train'. y_train is series but X_train is a data frame.  Do I have to change the y_train to be the same as X_train?